# Solving for Cos Exactly

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, solid-angle

How to solve $\cos(\dfrac{5\pi}{6})$ and  $\cos(\dfrac{7\pi}{6})$ exactly?

I couldn't use special triangles to solve this either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember these 2 identities: $$\begin{align} &\cos \left( \pi - x \right) = - \cos(x) \\ & \cos(\pi + x ) = -\cos (x) \end{align}$$

Or you can simply write: $$\cos (\pi - x) = \cos (\pi + x) =-\cos (x) $$

You need to find $\cos \left(\cfrac{5\pi}{6}\right)$. Try to break this down in order to use the above identities.

You can write $\cos \left(\cfrac{5\pi}{6}\right)$ as $\cos \left( \cfrac{6\pi - \pi}{6}\right)$

Or: $$\cos \left(\cfrac{6\pi}{6} - \cfrac{\pi}{6} \right) = \cos \left(\pi - \cfrac{\pi}{6} \right) $$

Now, you may use $\cos \left( \pi - x \right) = -\cos x$ identity here.

For the second part: $\cos \left(\cfrac{7\pi}{6}\right) = ? $

Break $\cfrac{7\pi}{6}$ into: $\color{blue}{\cfrac{6\pi + \pi}{6}}$

So, you get:

$$\cos \left( \pi + \cfrac{\pi}{6} \right)$$

Thus, you can use the identity of $\cos (\pi + x) = -\cos x$

Comment: ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}+1$

Comment: Thank You Jika for the +1 :)

Comment: I would just use the unit circle ^.^

Comment: Do those identities also work for sin and tan?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus: No, but there are analogous versions. The ones for sine (and cosine) can be seen by drawing out generic triangles. The ones for tangent are better done algebraically once you know the sine and cosine ones.

Answer (score 9):

**HINT**:
$$\cos(\dfrac{\pi}{6})=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$
$$\dfrac{5\pi}{6}=\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{6}.$$
$$\dfrac{7\pi}{6}=\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{6}.$$
$$\cos(\pi+x)=-\cos x.$$
$$\cos(-x)=\cos x.$$

Comment: cos(-x) = cos x .. I think you have done a typo there.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I fixed it.

Comment: Looks fine now. :)

Comment: LaTeX tip : Instead of using $ \$ \$ $ at each line, you may just use the code like this : $$\begin{align} & \cos (\pi + x) = -\cos x \\ & \cos(-x) = \cos x  \end{align}$$

Comment: ${}{}{}{}$. Thanks.